# Autofill SUMIF sentence through large table with input from both rows and columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I have a problem with autofill of an SUMIF sentence through a large table (around 10 000 rows)
The SUMIF sentence I need to autofill the table with is show below: 
(Hvis = IF in norwegian).

```
   B2 =SUMMERHVIS(I$139:I$143;"=x";'3 - Projects'!$J$26:$J$30)  
    C2 =SUMMERHVIS(J$139:J$143;"=x";'3 - Projects'!$J$26:$J$30) 
    D2 =SUMMERHVIS(K$139:K$143;"=x";'3 - Projects'!$J$26:$J$30)

    B3 =SUMMERHVIS(I$139:I$143;"=x";'3 - Projects'!$K$26:$K$30)                 
    C3  =SUMMERHVIS(J$139:J$143;"=x";'3 - Projects'!$K$26:$K$30)                                       
    D3 =SUMMERHVIS(K$139:K$143;"=x";'3 - Projects'!$K$26:$K$30)

   B4 =SUMMERHVIS(I$139:I$143;"=x";'3 - Projects'!$L$26:$L$30)                             
   C4  =SUMMERHVIS(J$139:J$143;"=x";'3 - Projects'!$L$26:$L$30)                               
   D4  =SUMMERHVIS(K$139:K$143;"=x";'3 - Projects'!$L$26:$L$30)
```

There are 52 columns and 100 rows for each project.

Now I only have code for 10 resource types and I need to autofill the rest of the rows and colums. Since I am reffering to colums when I autofill rows the columnletter does not change, is there something else I should add in the rows to make it work?

Hope some of you know what to do so I dont have to do fill 10 000 rows manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `=INDIRECT()` formula with generated address:

```
=SUMIF(I$139:I$143,"=x",INDIRECT("'3 - Projects'!"&ADDRESS(26,ROW()+7,1)&":"&ADDRESS(30,ROW()+7,1)))
```

(change `,` to `;` if neccesary).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, the formula by it self works great. But when I try to drag it out for autofill the Column numbers (Row() +7) does not change. Even if I help excel understand by making 3 rows. It jusy copies the formula. Do you have any idea?